# CPLEX Tree Memory Exceeds Given Limit

Tags: python, cplex, modeling, mixed-integer-programming

I am solving a model using CPLEX (version 12.8.0) on Python (3.5), and I have set the tree memory limit to 200MB with the following line:

```
model=cplex.Cplex()
model.parameters.mip.limits.treememory.set(200)
```

However, when CPLEX is solving the problem I can see that the tree memory limit is exceeded. Here is a small part of the output CPLEX provides:

```
CPXPARAM_Read_DataCheck                          1
CPXPARAM_MIP_Limits_TreeMemory                   200
Tried aggregator 3 times.
MIP Presolve eliminated 4488 rows and 2584 columns.
MIP Presolve modified 440 coefficients.
Aggregator did 211 substitutions.
Reduced MIP has 1550 rows, 2286 columns, and 8633 nonzeros.
Reduced MIP has 2285 binaries, 0 generals, 0 SOSs, and 0 indicators.
Presolve time = 0.01 sec. (16.76 ticks)
Probing changed sense of 682 constraints.
Probing time = 0.02 sec. (12.30 ticks)
Cover probing fixed 0 vars, tightened 2 bounds.
Tried aggregator 2 times.
MIP Presolve eliminated 379 rows and 261 columns.
Aggregator did 354 substitutions.
Reduced MIP has 817 rows, 1671 columns, and 6118 nonzeros.
Reduced MIP has 1670 binaries, 0 generals, 0 SOSs, and 0 indicators.
Presolve time = 0.02 sec. (9.17 ticks)
Probing time = 0.00 sec. (2.42 ticks)
Tried aggregator 1 time.
Reduced MIP has 817 rows, 1671 columns, and 6118 nonzeros.
Reduced MIP has 1670 binaries, 0 generals, 0 SOSs, and 0 indicators.
Presolve time = 0.00 sec. (5.53 ticks)
Probing time = 0.02 sec. (2.41 ticks)
Clique table members: 4112.
MIP emphasis: balance optimality and feasibility.
MIP search method: dynamic search.
Parallel mode: deterministic, using up to 16 threads.
Root relaxation solution time = 0.02 sec. (15.00 ticks)

        Nodes                                         Cuts/
   Node  Left     Objective  IInf  Best Integer    Best Bound    ItCnt     Gap

      0     0        0.6436    93                      0.6436      563         
*     0+    0                            0.7068        0.6436             8.95%
      0     0        0.6612    40        0.7068      Cuts: 21     2006    6.45%
      0     0        0.6936    26        0.7068      Cuts: 47     3177    1.87%
      0     0        0.6936    16        0.7068       Cuts: 7     3199    1.87%
*     0+    0                            0.7052        0.6936             1.64%
*     0+    0                            0.7038        0.6936             1.45%
*     0+    0                            0.7032        0.6936             1.36%
      0     0        0.6936    16        0.7032       Cuts: 4     3207    1.36%
      0     0        0.6936     8        0.7032       Cuts: 3     3209    1.36%
      0     0        0.6936    12        0.7032       Cuts: 7     3211    1.36%
*     0+    0                            0.7025        0.6936             1.26%
*     0+    0                            0.7023        0.6936             1.24%
*     0+    0                            0.7004        0.6936             0.97%
*     0+    0                            0.7002        0.6936             0.94%
      0     2        0.6936     4        0.7002        0.6936     3211    0.94%
Elapsed time = 1.41 sec. (428.81 ticks, tree = 0.01 MB, solutions = 8)
   2423  1530        0.6940     6        0.7002        0.6936    55132    0.94%
   4810  3104        0.6942    55        0.7002        0.6936   136130    0.94%
   5053  3464        0.6936     6        0.7002        0.6936   156078    0.94%
*  5066+ 2314                            0.7002        0.6936             0.93%
   6432   939        0.6939    10        0.7002        0.6936   173197    0.93%
*  7408+ 1360                            0.7002        0.6936             0.93%
*  8047+ 1859                            0.6994        0.6936             0.83%
*  8054+ 1859                            0.6991        0.6936             0.79%
*  8071+ 1859                            0.6990        0.6936             0.78%
   8585  2521        0.6950    29        0.6990        0.6936   229404    0.78%
*  9647+ 2981                            0.6990        0.6936             0.78%
  10623  3805        0.6943     8        0.6990        0.6936   292482    0.78%
  12524  5185        0.6936    12        0.6990        0.6936   349319    0.78%
  14150  6184        0.6979    12        0.6990        0.6936   411309    0.78%
  15589  7036        0.6936    12        0.6990        0.6936   464161    0.78%
  21190 10586        0.6954    10        0.6990        0.6936   691907    0.78%
Elapsed time = 9.45 sec. (3633.93 ticks, tree = 14.03 MB, solutions = 12)
  27132 13464        0.6939     6        0.6990        0.6936   897828    0.78%
  33463 17414        0.6976    72        0.6990        0.6936  1140445    0.78%
  39362 20967        cutoff              0.6990        0.6936  1352771    0.78%
  45328 24329        0.6959    24        0.6990        0.6936  1589213    0.78%
  49117 26447        0.6941    16        0.6990        0.6936  1709406    0.78%
  53573 28526        0.6988    14        0.6990        0.6936  1840273    0.78%
  59600 31555        0.6940    20        0.6990        0.6936  2034130    0.78%
  64734 34366        0.6983    12        0.6990        0.6936  2227637    0.78%
  70003 36328        0.6960    11        0.6990        0.6936  2359117    0.78%
  75688 39733        cutoff              0.6990        0.6936  2566606    0.78%
Elapsed time = 41.56 sec. (13173.08 ticks, tree = 48.70 MB, solutions = 12)
  80714 42809        0.6936    14        0.6990        0.6936  2747238    0.78%
  85628 45852        cutoff              0.6990        0.6936  2934644    0.78%
  91017 47777        cutoff              0.6990        0.6936  3044415    0.78%
  96150 51060        cutoff              0.6990        0.6936  3240496    0.78%
 100183 53082        0.6939    22        0.6990        0.6936  3372181    0.78%
 104757 55358        0.6948    17        0.6990        0.6936  3504114    0.78%
 108567 57349        0.6941    38        0.6990        0.6936  3642485    0.78%
 112759 59990        0.6972    52        0.6990        0.6936  3838475    0.78%
 116924 61965        0.6936    17        0.6990        0.6936  3992419    0.78%
 120748 63855        0.6976    38        0.6990        0.6936  4142406    0.78%
Elapsed time = 80.03 sec. (22712.25 ticks, tree = 76.52 MB, solutions = 12)
 124945 66729        0.6987    15        0.6990        0.6936  4340107    0.78%
 128747 67974        0.6964    14        0.6990        0.6936  4426483    0.78%
 132815 70342        0.6971    20        0.6990        0.6936  4590133    0.78%
 137230 72480        0.6949    57        0.6990        0.6936  4728398    0.78%
 140595 74229        0.6945    16        0.6990        0.6936  4843942    0.78%
 144796 75463        0.6936    25        0.6990        0.6936  4921865    0.78%
 148631 78367        cutoff              0.6990        0.6936  5103735    0.78%
 151982 79847    infeasible              0.6990        0.6936  5222935    0.78%
 155252 81499        cutoff              0.6990        0.6936  5347092    0.78%
 158662 83266        0.6938    34        0.6990        0.6936  5475973    0.78%
Elapsed time = 124.47 sec. (32250.79 ticks, tree = 102.49 MB, solutions = 12)
 161875 84516        0.6966    16        0.6990        0.6936  5559606    0.78%
 165468 86357        cutoff              0.6990        0.6936  5693642    0.78%
 169025 88181        0.6939    33        0.6990        0.6936  5835267    0.78%
 172541 89898        0.6988    30        0.6990        0.6936  5948795    0.78%
 175634 91381        0.6940    68        0.6990        0.6936  6047618    0.78%
 178673 92412        0.6953    29        0.6990        0.6936  6121595    0.78%
 182082 93907        0.6962    30        0.6990        0.6936  6221487    0.78%
 185394 96002        0.6949    13        0.6990        0.6936  6365702    0.78%
 188557 97052        0.6951    30        0.6990        0.6936  6424015    0.78%
 191001 98697        0.6936    41        0.6990        0.6936  6533472    0.78%
Elapsed time = 172.78 sec. (41792.01 ticks, tree = 122.26 MB, solutions = 12)
 194391 100271        0.6952    34        0.6990        0.6936  6630958    0.78%
 198117 101304        cutoff              0.6990        0.6936  6704953    0.78%
 202221 103028        0.6969    35        0.6990        0.6936  6816666    0.78%
 205676 105462        0.6959    17        0.6990        0.6936  6937443    0.78%
 208991 107087        cutoff              0.6990        0.6936  7048611    0.78%
 212475 108308        cutoff              0.6990        0.6936  7140082    0.78%
 216686 110827        0.6937    28        0.6990        0.6936  7296816    0.78%
 220245 112480        0.6956    37        0.6990        0.6936  7393759    0.78%
 223885 113281        0.6936    38        0.6990        0.6936  7443885    0.78%
 227860 115463        0.6936    20        0.6990        0.6936  7558942    0.78%
Elapsed time = 226.20 sec. (51330.66 ticks, tree = 144.28 MB, solutions = 12)
 232326 118130        0.6954    28        0.6990        0.6936  7706688    0.78%
 236399 120760        0.6940    28        0.6990        0.6936  7842887    0.78%
 240727 122457        0.6960    12        0.6990        0.6936  7938673    0.78%
 244267 124044        0.6936    36        0.6990        0.6936  8012021    0.78%
 247674 125301        0.6945    37        0.6990        0.6936  8088291    0.78%
 251801 127756        cutoff              0.6990        0.6936  8216958    0.78%
 255986 129474        0.6953    20        0.6990        0.6936  8316183    0.78%
 260128 131871        0.6937    18        0.6990        0.6936  8454527    0.78%
 264552 133259        cutoff              0.6990        0.6936  8527110    0.78%
 267759 135770        0.6936    13        0.6990        0.6936  8666467    0.78%
Elapsed time = 278.97 sec. (60870.96 ticks, tree = 167.07 MB, solutions = 12)
 271816 136668        cutoff              0.6990        0.6936  8711687    0.78%
 276209 139235        0.6938    48        0.6990        0.6936  8840350    0.78%
 280605 141372        0.6938    14        0.6990        0.6936  8954598    0.78%
 284383 143303        cutoff              0.6990        0.6936  9066732    0.78%
 287873 144999        0.6937    20        0.6990        0.6936  9175722    0.78%
 290803 146488        0.6955    28        0.6990        0.6936  9282171    0.78%
 293687 147657    infeasible              0.6990        0.6936  9384362    0.78%
 297131 149221        cutoff              0.6990        0.6936  9518357    0.78%
 301280 150365        cutoff              0.6990        0.6936  9598681    0.78%
 305437 152082        0.6936    37        0.6990        0.6936  9715685    0.78%
Elapsed time = 330.81 sec. (70410.38 ticks, tree = 184.94 MB, solutions = 12)
 309518 154719        0.6946    38        0.6990        0.6936  9881698    0.78%
 312860 156625        0.6937    15        0.6990        0.6936  9993540    0.78%
 316982 157547        0.6939    21        0.6990        0.6936 10045896    0.78%
 320337 159358        0.6937    20        0.6990        0.6936 10168338    0.78%
 324403 161807        0.6943    16        0.6990        0.6936 10331010    0.78%
 329372 163432        0.6937    53        0.6990        0.6936 10407142    0.78%
 334168 166177        0.6958    32        0.6990        0.6936 10539685    0.78%
 337917 168217        cutoff              0.6990        0.6936 10640231    0.78%
 341835 169880    infeasible              0.6990        0.6936 10704784    0.78%
 345692 171568        0.6950    14        0.6990        0.6936 10800146    0.78%
Elapsed time = 380.61 sec. (79950.04 ticks, tree = 222.94 MB, solutions = 12)
 350724 172982        cutoff              0.6990        0.6936 10865751    0.78%
 355189 176099        0.6936    68        0.6990        0.6936 11001504    0.78%
 359288 178287        0.6953    49        0.6990        0.6936 11121256    0.78%
 362833 179458        0.6942    14        0.6990        0.6936 11193047    0.78%
 365940 181006        0.6963    12        0.6990        0.6936 11300814    0.78%
 369967 182095        0.6940    10        0.6990        0.6936 11365287    0.78%
 373324 184924        0.6937    35        0.6990        0.6936 11518928    0.78%
 377405 186710        0.6969    38        0.6990        0.6936 11636666    0.78%
 381649 187974        0.6966    65        0.6990        0.6936 11710453    0.78%
 397357 195848        0.6945    30        0.6990        0.6936 12161768    0.78%
Elapsed time = 447.92 sec. (92351.11 ticks, tree = 249.69 MB, solutions = 12)
 413725 203202        0.6937    22        0.6990        0.6936 12562613    0.78%
 428536 210242        0.6962     8        0.6990        0.6936 12988674    0.78%
```

What is the problem here? Am I missing a few steps?